# How to automatically update new hostnames inside local network?

Tags: networking, dns, lan

I'm trying to make some simple decentralized DNS for my local network.

The trouble is that every time I add a new machine, the other machines on the net can't find its name automatically because it has to be manually added to the resolver's table; I want this to be done automatically.

Let's say that I have a computer with the hostname `continua` that was recently added to the network and has a dynamic IP address, so to connect to that machine from another point on the net via SSH, FTP, `ping`, etc., I first need to know its IP, what forces me to scan the network for a new device or check the router DHCP table.

So instead of calling:

```
ssh continua
```

I have to do it by its dynamic IP:

```
ssh 192.168.1.xxx
```

The simplest way to solve that is to set the new hostname table on the router's DNS, but it becomes impractical if I have to do this many times.

I plan to make every computer on my network able to resolve its name via simple DNS running locally and then send this information to the upper DNS on my router.

But I don't know how to do this middle step. I actually installed `dnsmasq` on one of my computers, and it correctly resolves itself over the local network, so what I am thinking is there a way to add broadcast as a DNS server in `resolv.conf`? Something like `192.168.1.255`?

Comment: You don't broadcast to a DNS server, you add the server's IP address to `/etc/resolv.conf`. Do you have DDNS enabled on your router/DNS server/DHCP server?

Comment: you mean something as no-ip.org? you're misunderstang me then, what I mean is inside of my local network. I think that I solved it by enabling avahi, that does a 0 conf discovery and publishing of new hosts over the net. Anyway I still have some troubles with dnsmasq as my machines are resolving as 127.0.0.1 instead of the actual ip over the net. I think it's something on the hosts file.

Comment: I was actually suggesting something like OpenWRT for dnsmasq. Avahi, as you found out is another mDNS solution. Since no-ip.org never sees your private network, it is not a solution.

Answer (score 0):

An option is to install `avahi-daemon  if you are running some kind of Linux, or the mDNS (Multicast DNS Service Discovery) solution provided by your system.

Then you can use the special domain `.local` to find computers (those running the service), so `ping continua.local` will work right away, no maintenance needed.

Comment: Yeah I did that. Inded the problem was that avahi was disabled on one of my machines, solved by enabling it

Comment: Now my problem is that as I installed dnsmasq and I found it neat and potentially usefull that everymachine could resolve its name. The problem is that they return their loopback address (127.0.0.1) intead of it's outer address (eg. 192.168.1.2)